# Why am I getting empty set auxiliaryFiles in production mode in webpack

Tags: webpack

I have a loader. And it emits a file:

```
module.exports = async function () {
    const callback = this.async();
    const contents = JSON.stringify({});

    this.emitFile('foo.json', contents);

    callback(null, 'export {};');
}
```

And I have a plugin that should process the file that I emitted:

```
class CustomPlugin {
    apply(compiler) {
        compiler.hooks.thisCompilation.tap('CustomPlugin', (compilation) => {
            compilation.hooks.processAssets.tapAsync(
                {
                    name: 'CustomPlugin',
                    stage: compiler.webpack.Compilation.PROCESS_ASSETS_STAGE_ADDITIONAL,
                },
                (_, callback) => {
                    console.log(compilation.chunks);
            
                    callback();
                }
            );
        });
    }
}
```

This is my `webpack.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'test',
    mode: 'development',
    entry: {
        index: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.js'),
    },
    output: {
        clean: true,
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
        filename: '[name].[contenthash:4].js'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js'],
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.custom$/,
                use: [
                    '../src/loader/index.js'
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: [/node_modules/],
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: [
                            ['@babel/preset-env', { targets: "defaults" }]
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new CustomPlugin()
    ],
    target: 'web'
};
```

The Chunk object I've logged has an `auxiliaryFiles` field. This is a `Set`, which in `development` mode contains the name of the file that I emitted from the loader. And in `production` mode `auxiliaryFiles` is empty.

I did not find any documentation about this field and I want to understand why the behavior is different.

[Here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/11425#issuecomment-698837871) I found the only mention, but nothing is said about the difference in work in different modes.